# How to change the date display format if the data is taken from an array?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to change the date display format if the data is taken from an array?

What do you need to do for this? If  do so, it will turn out nonsense.

```
{{row[column.lowercaseValue] | date}}
```

html:

```
<table mat-table class="tb" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortDisableClear matSortActive="NAME"
matSortDirection="asc">
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="column.value" *ngFor="let column of allCols;">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header (click)="load()">
        {{column.displayName}}
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        {{row[column.lowercaseValue]}}
    </td>
</ng-container>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

ts:

```
const COLS = [
  { value: "NAME", lowercaseValue: "name", displayName: 'Full name' },
  { value: "EMAIL", lowercaseValue: "email", displayName: 'E-mail' },
  { value: "MSG", lowercaseValue: "msg", displayName: 'Message' },
  { value: "DATE", lowercaseValue: "date", displayName: 'Date' }
];
```

JSON:

```
{
    "rowCount": 2944,
    "user": [
        {
            "name": "Jaden Adrian Sanders",
            "email": "sowixowew@ionemail.net",
            "msg": "No binding defined",
            "date": "2019-08-16T02:30:03.000Z"
        },
...
}
```

Or can  be somehow set globally so that the date is displayed as I need?

Comment: In your code nowhere you mentioned date object

Comment: @Chaitanya  
 `{ value: "DATE", lowercaseValue: "date", displayName: 'Date' }`

Comment: can you share the object with the actual value of the date...

Comment: @AkberIqbal Need to show how the date is currently displayed?

Comment: Can you share the array with values that you have... ?

Comment: @AkberIqbal Added by

Comment: There's no need to store both lowercase and uppercase versions, there are standard pipes for that called `lowercase` and I've forgotten what the other is called.

Comment: normal pipes are working on the date format that you shared in your JSON... check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdzm9e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the `column.value` is `DATE` so that the pipe will only apply for the `date` fields in your `dataSource`.

Try this

```html
{{column.value === 'DATE' ? (row[column.lowercaseValue] | date): row[column.lowercaseValue]}}
```